# Use Tomato router as ethernet hub?

Tags: router, ethernet, nas, tomato, hub

I'm running tomato 1.28 on my N600 netgear router, and I have the following situation:

I have an ethernet cord coming directly from a normal router (I'll call it router1), that I would like to use to provide internet to the tomato router (router2).

I then have multiple Ethernet cables I would like to plug into router2, using it just like it is your average Ethernet hub, only with an NAS server on it.

It would also be cool if I could use the WiFi part too in the same way, but it is not needed.

I've seen multiple tutorials but they use terms I don't know since I've never worked with tomato before, and I'm not really sure how routers work. Is what I'm asking possible?

**EDIT**: I was able to set up router2 as a hub, or at least so I thought. It allows all devices connected to it to connect to router1, but only one is getting internet. When running the Windows network troubleshooter it says `Your DNS server might be unavailable`. I tired flushing my dns and releasing and renewing my ip. No mass.

**EDIT 2**: It appears this is another problem and is only for LAN ports not wireless. I'm thus moving it to a new question. since the accepted answer did technicall answer my question.

Comment: r600? Doesn't not exist according to https://www.netgear.com/support/ ...

Comment: N600. Sorry, fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Simply decide which device - router1 or tomato - will be the DHCP server.  Disable as needed, configure the other as needed, and you are done.

Comment: Ok I did that and it works, however I had not set up the NAS function yet. How can I connect to router2 now? 192.168.1.1 connects to Router1.

Comment: What IP did you assign router2 ?

Comment: Ok I did that and was able to connect to it. However, I have another problem, it is only giving internet access to one device.